# Reportlab Rounded Rect

Tags: python, reportlab

In the documentation and source code I see lots of references to a rounded rect, however, I cannot seem to draw one.

I am drawing a normal rectangle with:

```
canvas.rect(15, 625, 250, 125, fill=0)
```

What arguments do I pass to round of the corners?

Comment: Try `canvas.roundRect(self, x, y, width, height, radius, stroke=1, fill=0)` (found that [here](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-reference.pdf)).

Comment: @robertklep not `self`.

Comment: @AJ been too long since I wrote Python :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try calling [`canvas.roundRect(left, bottom, width, height, radius)`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reportlab-users/w7Gh6_DE1n4):

```
canvas.roundRect(15, 625, 250, 125, 4, stroke=1, fill=0)
```

Should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I could not import roundRect or see it as a function in the source, so was assuming it was a custom function, turns out its an import that comes with "Rect". Thanks